# nodejs empty file on 'finish' after pipe()

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I write a readable stream to a file and want to know when it is finished so I can access the file on the disk.
I listen to the `finish` event but when I do a `stat` in the listener the file size is 0. After some delay the size is correct.

Is this normal behavior?

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) the event is emitted when *all data has been flushed to the underlying system*.

```
var ws = fs.createWriteStream(path);
file.pipe(ws); // file is a readable stream
ws.on('finish', function() {
    try {
        stat = fs.statSync(path); // stat.size: 0
    }
    catch (err) { /*...*/ }
});
```

Comment: Can you try the async `fs.stat` method? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback

Comment: Why would the async version be different? `stat` is there just to show the problem, I want to do `gm(path)` instead, which fails because of the empty file.

Comment: Since you said it works at a later time, I'm wondering if there is a bug where that event is fired too soon when there are other JS commands on the event loop (to finish writing the file). The async version would let any pending commands complete. Not really an answer, but could provide additional details about the underlying issue.

Comment: I tried the async `stat` and got the same result.

Comment: in other languages, you have access to [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html). But try looking for JavaScript, fs and sync - you'll get mad. There appears to be [fsync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_fsync_fd_callback) in node 7+ but I couldn't reliably get it to work either :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finish` event is emitted when all data is written to the stream but file may not be closed at that time. You can listen the `close` event which is emitted once the file handler is closed.

```
ws.once('close', function() {
    try {
        stat = fs.statSync(path);
    }
    catch (err) { /*...*/ }
});
```

Comment: This seems to work but the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.10.x/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) does not mention any `close` event for a writeable stream... Also in the source code I see that it only emits `finish`. What am I missing?

Comment: yes, doc only has `open` event but you can look at the source [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1758-L1781) and [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1831-L1832)

Comment: I see now, thanks. I wonder why this is undocumented. I accept your answer as it explains what is happening, however I am not completely happy with this solution. Is there any other way to write a readable stream to a file (apart from processing the `data` events)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way other than `pipe()` or `data` event.

Comment: @sceid This event actually is documented under `fs.WriteStream`: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_event_close_1

Comment: In my case, even when waiting for `close`, I can't immediately afterwards read that same file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct capture event example

```
var ws = fs.createWriteStream(path);
var stream = file.pipe(ws); // file is a readable stream
stream.on('finish', function() {
    try {
        stat = fs.statSync(path); // stat.size: 0
    }
    catch (err) { /*...*/ }
});
```